# Reducing wire number in a cable

Tags: usb

First let me say that I'm a mechanical engineer so I'm unfamiliar with a lot of things you'll consider basic.

I have a PCB that carries two cameras, and transfer their data to a Raspberry Pi 4. The cameras successfully function with power supply from only one of the USBs, the other USB is connected to the PCB's connector only by it's data+ and data- wires. Again, the second USB is connect the Pi 'normally' goes through my thick cable, and at the other end connects to the PCB only with data+ and data- wires.
I need to reduce the number of wires in the cable, so the question is can I eliminate the 5 V and ground all together so the Pi will receive a USB connector that has only two active wires **without damaging the signal**?

Comment: I am not 100% sure I have understood your setup clearly. A schematics or at least a block diagram could help a lot.

Comment: Hard to tell without a schematic. Probably not.

Comment: Your ‘thick’ cable would have to be suitable for USB signals - shielded twisted pair at a minimum but even that might be too high capacitance for USB. As well USB isn’t particularly robust, so you don’t want to send it any significant distance. 

I wouldn’t recommend what you are suggesting.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t simply use a USB hub instead? That would allow you to have a single 4-wire USB cable from the Pi to the hub.

Comment: A ground is absolutely required.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing VBUS between endpoints isn’t compliant with the USB spec. Nor is connecting two VBUS lines together.

USB hosts are obliged to provide VBUS. Endpoints have the choice of using VBUS for power, power+reset, reset, or not at all and instead rely on DP/DM for reset.

In fact USB endpoints watch DP/DM for reset so they can support self-power modes. Knowing this, you could inject 5V separately to the cameras and save the one wire (that is, the cameras would be self-powered.)

But your idea of eliminating the ground? Nope. Unlike Ethernet, USB needs a shared ground.

So that means you need at least 3 pairs to make the connection: GND and +5V, and the two DP/DM pairs. And those pairs need to be impedance controlled if they run any significant distance (more than 1 foot or so.)

That’s a lot of work to save two wires. Your EE will hate you for it.

Answer (score 0):

so you have 2 USB plugs but only 6 conductors,  (sharing the +5 and 0V conductors between the two devices. that should work.

If you check the raspberry pi schematic you'll see that all the +5s are connected togetherm and same for the 0Vs.